# serving static files from subdomain

Tags: django

I have a site developed with django at www.example.com

I want that django insert/serve static files ( images ) in/from media.example.com

How do I do ?

.

Thanks ^_______^

Comment: What HTTP server are you using?

Comment: I am using Apache. But I am able to use also lightpd and nginx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django's ability to serve static files is meant to be used **for development only**. Django is a web application framework, and the webservers should be much better at serving static content. ([relevant docs here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/))

You should configure your webserver to serve static content from media.example.com, and skip django for such URLs.